# Tomcat9 サービス停止に1分以上かかります

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, windows-server

Tomcat9 Windows サービス停止に1分以上かかります。
早める方法はありませんか？

Comment: この記事が同件かもしれません。[Tomcat 9 takes 1 minute to stop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54211863/9014308) 解決マークの後に付いた回答が最終回答でしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

なぜ遅いのか、原因を調査する必要があります。

まずはTomcatのログ（`logs/catalina.out`）を確認して、サービス停止中に関連しそうなメッセージが出ていないか確認して下さい。それで原因を特定できなければ（それで特定できる可能性は低いですが）、次はサービス停止処理中にスレッドダンプを複数回取得して下さい。

スレッドダンプには複数のスレッドのスタックトレースが表示されているので、遅延の原因と考えられそうなものが無いか確認してみて下さい。おそらくデプロイされているアプリケーションに関する何らかのスレッドが残っているのではないかと予想します。分からなければ、スレッドダンプを質問本文に追記して下さい。